# build dynamical JSON/LIST obj in Python

Tags: python, json

I'm a real Python newbee and I'm having problems creating a JSON/LIST obj.
What I want to end up with is the following JSON to send o an API

```
{
  "request": {
    "slice": [
      {
        "origin": "AMS",
        "destination": "SYD",
        "date": "2015-06-23"
      }
    ],
    "passengers": {
      "adultCount": 1,
      "infantInLapCount": 0,
      "infantInSeatCount": 0,
      "childCount": 0,
      "seniorCount": 0
    },
    "solutions": 20,
    "refundable": false
  }
}
```

I figured to make a list and then to convert to JSON with the dumps() function. This works. The thing is, I need to change the date field with an iterator to add a day, but I'm stuck on changing this field.

Any advice?

thx!

Comment: `j["request"]["slice"][0]["date"] = new data`?

Comment: You might want to share the code you are stuck with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your question is a bit vague i can only guess that you're trying to modify the JSON version of your data directly, while you should modify the Python object *before* converting it into JSON... something like this:

```
d = {
  "request": {
    "slice": [
      {
        "origin": "AMS",
        "destination": "SYD",
        "date": "2015-06-23"
      }
    ],
    "passengers": {
      "adultCount": 1,
      "infantInLapCount": 0,
      "infantInSeatCount": 0,
      "childCount": 0,
      "seniorCount": 0
    },
    "solutions": 20,
    "refundable": False  # note how this is python False, not js false!
  }
}

# then you can do:
d["request"]["slice"][0]["date"] = "2015-05-23"

# and finally convert to json:
j = json.dumps(d)
```

If it happens that you get JSON as a string, you should first convert it into a python object so you can work on it:

```
# if j is your json string, convert it into a python object
d = json.loads(j)

# then do your modifications as above:
d["request"]["slice"][0]["date"] = "2015-05-23"

# and finally convert back to json:
j = json.dumps(d)
```

Comment: thanks, this was what I needed. I build the json like the first codeblock you put in your post. The updating of the date field was the thing that wasn't clear to me. Looks simple, but my problem was the path to the field.